# Showing objects after given time in x3d

Tags: javascript, time, x3d

I am trying to create an animation in x3d by gradually having more spheres appear in a model. Is there any possibiliy doing this within the x3d namespace? 
I have tried using a javascript for loop to access every sphere and change it's `transparency`-attribute, but this leads to the old problem of having delays in javascript (effectively locking up my browser).

Ideally, I'd be looking for an attribute/tag allowing me to set the `appearance time` for each sphere. Alternatively, a javascript snippet starting the progress of having the spheres appear would suffice.

No code snippets here, this question is on more of a theoretical niveau.

Answer (score 1):

The browser issue is probably due to the transparency attribute used on the spheres.
You can add a Switch node for every sphere that you have in the scene, with the whichChoice attribute set to -1, this indicating that the sphere is not shown (rendered). Then you can use a TimeSensor to trigger the visibility of any of the spheres by setting the whichChoice attribute of the Switch node to 0.
*Note that each Switch node has only one children (choice) and that is the Sphere node.*